# Laravel matrix levels of user

Tags: php, laravel

Currently i am working on laravel i have created users with id and id is given to those who have referred by id user and id is save into parent_id of that user who get referred
here is structure,

```
id   parent_id
1      0
2      1
3      1
4      3
5      2
6      3
7      1
8      6
9      2
10     4
```

so i want to ask how i count the level in matrix  using code in php laravel and give process like

level 1 = 10% ,level 2 = 8% ,level 3 = 6%,level 4 = 4% ,level 5 = 2% ,level 7 = 2% ,level 8 = 2%

and vice versa
parent_id is user_id

Comment: parent_id is user's id, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a one-to-many relationship in User modal.

```
public function parents()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Modals\User', 'parent_id');
}
```

In your UserController

```
public function index()
  {
    return User::with("parents")->get();
  }
```

This should return:

```
[
 [
   id: 1,
   name: "..",
   ....,
   parents: [[user 2, user 3, user 7]]
 ],
 ...
]
```

Now, you can use parents array in each user to count, display, set levels, etc.

Comment: **Do i need to create class of App\Models\User**

Comment: You should have User model already. Just give its path. It's probably App\User if not App\Models\User

Comment: i did but its not working
is there any other way

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Method App\Http\Controllers\RegistersController::hasMany does not exist.

Comment: hasMany is an eloquent relation function and it should be in your User model, not in controller. BTW, I removed "$comment = " part from the index function. It was wrong.